# Checkbox column in grid with paging

Tags: checkboxes, grid

I have a grid with a column of checkboxes that allows to select multiple rows. When any row is selected user can do some kind of action on them. Grid has several pages, sorting and filtering are enabled.
My question is: should the state of selected checkboxes be remembered when user changes page? For example, user selectes two rows on first page, goes to second, selects another row there and executes the action on selected rows. Should the action affect rows from first page as well or only the second?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Because of that pagination, when you start clicking the checkboxes you should be able navigate through pages and select other items. Otherwise bulk action will be impossible across different pages.

Gmail has a similar behaviour when you select emails across several pages. Check that out.

[image]